# new Date() set to 31 december 2014 says 1st december instead

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a string to a Date object, and it works for all days except for December 31st where by object says December 1st instead of 31st. I have no idea why. Here is my `JavaScript` code:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setDate("31");
dt.setMonth("11");
dt.setFullYear("2014");
```

but my variable value is:

```
Mon Dec 01 2014 11:48:08 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
```

If I do the same for any other date, my object returns to the appropriate value. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: You're meant to pass integers to setMonth etc, not strings.

Comment: @funkybro integers seem to produce the same value.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a plunkr?

Comment: change the sequence of setting values!

Comment: you can use the `Date` constructor's parameters directly: `new Date(2014, 11, 31)`

Comment: btw. isn't 11th month November?

Comment: @jnovacho No.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Why are you calling `setXY` on a variable with the *current* datetime anyway? If you want a new datetime object, you should use `new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 11, 31))`

Comment: NOTE: the result posted in this example will be different depending on the current date. **The example code will produce CORRECT results if current month is January, March, ..., October, December**.

Comment: There are only 30 days in November (month 11) and one day forward would be 1 December. Perhaps somewhere down the line the time is mixed up because of the zero-indexing for months?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen No, the date is mixed up because the month _right now_ has only 30 days.

Comment: @jnovacho C's struct tm.tm_mon field represented the month as "months since January", thus numbering them from zero, and we've all been living with that original sin ever since.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

<del>`setMonth` should before `setDate`</del>: (*not safe for Months less than 31 days*)

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setFullYear(2014);
dt.setMonth(11);
dt.setDate(31);
```

And `setMonth`'s second parameter also could be used to set date.

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setFullYear(2014);
dt.setMonth(11, 31);
```

---

If no arguments are provided for the constructor, it will use **the current date and time** according to system settings.

So, using `setMonth` and `setDate` separately would still cause unexpected result.

If the values set are **greater than their logical range**, the value will be auto **adjusted to the adjacent value**.

For example, if today is `2014-09-30`, then

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setFullYear(2014); /* Sep 30 2014 */
dt.setMonth(1);       /* Mar 02 2014, see, here the auto adjustment occurs! */
dt.setDate(28);       /* Mar 28 2014 */
```

To avoid this, set the values using the constructor directly.

```
var dt = new Date(2014, 11, 31);
```

Comment: I just found it out, indeed, but it does not really make sense to me

Comment: @user2859409 it's probably because if you don't set the month first it takes the current month and then might sometimes wrap into next month (as per Jakub's answer below)

Comment: I'd hesitate to recommend that first block of code for months with fewer than 31 days.  If, for example, you want to set the date to September 15, but it's August 31 today, the date will wrap around to the next month and you will end up with October 15.  +1 for the second block of code: that's the better way to go.  I didn't even know the 2-argument form of `setMonth` existed.

Comment: Note that setting the month before the day can also be wrong.  Not in this case, though.  If it is October 31, then setMonth(10) will set the date to Nov 31 which will wrap to Dec 1.  setDate(31) then results in Dec 31.  So, always use the 2-argument setMonth().

Comment: @user2859409: it might become clearer if you check the value of `dt` after each method call: `var dt = new Date(); console.log(dt); dt.setDate("31"); console.log(dt); dt.setMonth("11"); console.log(dt); dt.setFullYear("2014"); console.log(dt);`. You’ll see that @FailingBullets is correct (at least when the current month of the date according to your computer’s clock has 30 days, like September does).

Comment: +1 but I would emphasize that the two month option is preferred to prevent side effects.

Comment: Right. Won't `SetMonth` with only a month parameter have problems if the current date is the 31st and you try to set a month that has fewer days? I'd say the constructor `new Date(...)` with the desired date for a parameter is vastly preferred.

Comment: If you don't want to set the values in teh constructor directly, it would probably be a good idea to use new Date(0) instead of new Date() - you probably don't want the current time of day on the object, too.

Answer (score 122):

The thing is, when you set a day first, you're still in the current month, so September. September has only 30 days so:

```
var dt = new Date(); /* today */
dt.setDate("31"); /* 1st Oct 2014 as should be by spec */
dt.setMonth("11"); /* 1st Dec 2014 */
dt.setFullYear("2014"); /* 1st Dec 2014 */
```

Comment: +1 - This is the kind of bug that will lie dormant all August, and then bite you in the butt come September ;)

Comment: It is NEVER right to set a date one component at a time, as there are failure cases with day first _and_ with month first, _and_ possibly with year first on 2/29.  You must set all three fields at the same time.

Comment: +1 and it should be an accepted answer, because it explains WHY you should set the month first. It's a very javascript WTF

Comment: Should be similar in other languages so not a "javascript WTF".

Comment: Why does the Date object not throw when an incorrect date is set?

Comment: One more reason to put the year first. Most significant first, least significant last, just like the decimal system.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt Of course you should set month first.  Your code failing every 31st of a month is much better than it failing every month that has 30 days.

Comment: @jww so you can do date math.  If I want to add 7 days to the current date, I can do `dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7)`. If today is Nov 29, it will convert "Nov 36" to "Dec 6". A separate DateAdd function might have been better, but it can't really be changed at this point...

Answer (score 25):

It's because the first thing you do is

```
dt.setDate(31)
```

This sets the current date to 31.  The current month is September which has 30 days, so it's wrapping it round.

If you were to print out the date after this point, it would say 1 October.

Comment: The funny thing is, this only popped up because he tried it during a month with 30 days. One month later and it would have just seemed to work okay.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your intent is to set year, month and date simultaneously you could use the [longer date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax):

> **new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);**
>
> [...]
>
> If at least two arguments are supplied, missing arguments are either
>   set to 1 (if day is missing) or 0 for all others.

So you would write:

```
var dt = new Date(2014, 11, 31);
```

As already established, setting one portion of date at a time can result in overflows:

```
var dt = new Date(2012, 1, 29); // Feb 29 2012
dt.setFullYear(2014);           // Mar 01 2014 instead of Feb 28 2014
```

Moreover, setting month before date can still cause unexpected overflow (answers that recommend changing the order of methods are incorrect):

```
var dt = new Date(2014, 0, 31); // Jan 31 2014
dt.setFullYear(2014);           // Jan 31 2014
dt.setMonth(1);                 // Mar 03 2014 instead of Feb 28 2014
dt.setDate(1);                  // Mar 01 2014
```

Comment: i like this answer, because it gives you the correct solution at the top, then explains why the broken solution doesn't work...

Answer (score 8):

The why of the behaviour and how to avoid it has been amply explained.

But the real error in your code is that you shouldn't use the default constructor: new Date().  Your code will result in a Date on Dec. 13 with the current time.  I doubt this is what you want.  You should use the Date constructor that takes year, month and day as parameters.

Comment: I suppose it was intended to be the comment on the accepted answer?

Comment: Not really.  It is an answer to the question "What did I wrong?"

Answer (score -2):

The answers made clear that the right order for setting the date is:

- setFullYear()
- setMonth()
- setDate()

I just want to point out that it´s also important to set the year at first, because of the 29. february in leapyears.

Comment: No. The order does not guarantee that the date will be set correctly. See comments below the accepted and most voted answers.

Comment: If your starting date is the 31st and you set it to month with fewer (like 30) days, you'll end up in the next month. So this just is not enough. To be safe you should set the date to something not higher than 28 before you set the month. And finally set the date again to its final value, if that is higher.

Answer (score -5):

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setFullYear(2014);
dt.setMonth(11);
dt.setDate(31);
```

Pass value as integer not string.. it will return u correct value..

---

**Update** - 
above description is not correct.. the main issue was you need to put these three line in proper sequence.. Even After I corrected the sequence I forgot to correct the description.. :P

Comment: No it does not, here is my test in chrome console :

    var dt = new Date();
undefined
    dt.setDate(31);
1412157761255
    dt.setMonth(11);
1417431761255
    dt.setFullYear(2014);
1417431761255
    dt
Mon Dec 01 2014 12:02:41 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type of the argument and everything to do with the sequence. You're mentioning the sequence as if it was a secondary thing...

Comment: While that code **works**, you've given **wrong** explanation, why.